# Create a method which simulates a class constructor

Tags: javascript

I want to create a method which automatically implemented when create an instance of an object, exactly like concept of class constructor.

```
function myString(string) {
  // Storing the length of the string.
  this.length = 0;
  // A private constructor which automatically implemented
  var __construct = function() {
    this.getLength();
  }();
  // Calculates the length of a string
  this.getLength = function() {
    for (var count in string) {
      this.length++;
    }
  };
}

// Implementation
var newStr = new myString("Hello");
document.write(newStr.length);
```

I have the following error message when implement the previous code:
`TypeError: this.getLength is not a function`.

---

**UPDATE**:
The problem was in `this` scope.
The following is constructor method after updade:

```
var __construct = function(that) {
  that.getLength();
}(this);
```

Comment: `this` in `__construct` is not what you think it is - once you fix that, you'll also need to move that code below where `this.getLength` is defined

Comment: @JaromandaX: Sorry, but I don't understand what do you mean about `this in __construct is not what you think it is`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Constructors in JavaScript objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114024/constructors-in-javascript-objects)

Comment: do you know what **this** is?

Comment: @JaromandaX: Yes, `this` is a reference to the object itself.

Comment: I've updated my code which works for what your trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't get it. What's the "private constructor" good for? What do you mean by "automatically implemented"? (Sounds like you're looking for the term "[immediately called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-this-iife-construct-in-javascript)") And why don't you simply drop that "inner" constructor and just put the `this.getLength();` statement that you want executed in your actual constructor, `myString`, that you already have?

Comment: Why don't you just use the constructor? What is the benefit of having another function that is "exactly like concept of class constructor" but isn't actually the constructor?

Comment: `Yes, this is a reference to the object itself.` - log `this` inside `__construct` to see that it isn't

Comment: @JaromandaX: I thank you, the problem was in `this` scope.

Answer (score 1):

Bergi's answer in this thread is far more relevant: [How to define private constructors in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21667149/how-to-define-private-constructors-in-javascript)

Though a bit crude you can create a method called `init` and then call that method at the bottom of your function so when you instantiate a new object that code shall be run.

```
  function myString(string) {

  //Initalization function
  this.init = function() {
    this.calcLength();
  }

  // Storing the length of the string.
  this.length = 0;

  this.getLength = function() {
    return this.length;
  }

  // Calculates the length of a string
  this.calcLength = function() {
    for (var count in string) {
      this.length++;
    }
  };

  this.init();
}

// Implementation
var newStr = new myString("Hello");
var element = document.getElementById('example');
element.innerText = newStr.getLength();
```

Edit: I'm aware there are better ways to achieve this, but this gets the job done.

Edit 2: Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ntygbfb6/3/

Comment: Don't use `init` methods. Simply place the respective code in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you. Your way is an alternative way but not what I want.

Comment: @Bergi I just read your answer in another thread +1 the implementation Is really good, I've learn't something new. Edited your answer into mine.